# Reference table rows differently in multiple tables in LaTeX

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, numbering, longtable, multirow

I'm making an interview.
I have a table with "Questions and Explanations" and a table with "Questions and Answers". 
I have labeled each row, so I can reference each question later on.
I would like to change the labeling, and also reference my Questions and Answers table different for each interview person:
I would like to number and label each row in my table so I can reference them later on.

I get the following output:
[image]
[image]

I would like the output to look like this:
[image]
[image]

Please help
Thank you

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[top=2.81cm, bottom=2.75cm,right=2cm, left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\usepackage{setspace}
   \onehalfspacing
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%% DETTE ER NUMERERING AF RÆKKER I TABELLER
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\newcounter{rowcntr}[table]
\makeatletter
% Assuming arabic numbers for the table number -- in case of bottom table caption, we have to increase the table number by one, only for output. 
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\@arabic{\numexpr\c@table+1}.\arabic{rowcntr}}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}c}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rowcntr}{0}}
%%% DETTE ER NUMERERING AF RÆKKER I TABELLER
\begin{document}
\section*{Interview questions}
The following table contains my interview questions and explanation

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|N| c | V{7.6cm} | V{7.6cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Question}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Explanation}} \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Interview phase 1}\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|C{17.5cm}|}{\textit{Text This phase focus on ...TextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextText TextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text }}\\ \hline
   \label{que:1} & A & Do you think ...? & This is a good question.\\
   \label{que:2} & C & Do you feel Text & This is a good question.\\
   \label{que:3} & E & What do you think of your previous boss & Relationship between employee and employer text Text textText text Text text Text text.\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Interview phase 2}\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|C{17.5cm}|}{\textit{Text This phase focus on ... }}\\ \hline
   \label{que:4} & D & Is this ...? & Good question.\\
   \label{que:5} & I & Do you like Text  & A good question.\\
   \label{que:6} & A & what do you think of your mother & Relationship \\ \hline

   \caption {Questions and explanation} \label{tab:interviewspg}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\section*{Interview answers person A}
The following section contains the answers from interviewperson A
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|N|  V{8.3cm} | V{8.3cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Question}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Answer}} \\ \hline
   \label{QA:1} &  Do you think ...? & Yes I think.\\
   \label{QA:2} &  Do you feel Text & I feel a lot of text.\\
   \label{QA:3} & What do you think of your previous boss & I hated him.\\
   \label{QA:3a} & \textbf{This is an unexpected follow up question} \textbf{Why did you hate him?} & \textbf{Because he was evil.}\\
   \label{QA:4} &  Is this ...? & Yes\\
   \label{QA:5} & Do you like Text  & Text is good.\\
   \label{QA6:6} & what do you think of your mother & I really like my mother \\ \hline

   \caption {Questions and answers} \label{tab:interviewspg}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\newpage
\section*{Interview answers person B}
The following section contains the answers from interviewperson B
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|N|  V{8.3cm} | V{8.3cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Question}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Answer}} \\ \hline
   \label{QB:1} &  Do you think ...? & No\\
   \label{QB:2} &  Do you feel Text & No you can't feel text\\
   \label{QB:3} & What do you think of your previous boss & She was okay\\
   \label{QB:4} &  Is this ...? & No\\
   \label{QB:5} & Do you like Text  & Text is bad.\\
   \label{QA6:6} & what do you think of your mother & I would like to not answer that \\ \hline

   \caption {Questions and answers} \label{tab:interviewspg}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I can see  you you have used code from my answer to your other question ;-) This is possible, of course, but the usual approach is to give at least some indication who wrote the originals of this (regardless who it is)

Comment: How can I indicate that you (or someone else) wrote the original code? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with a separate `interviewee` counter and a `\subquest` command to change temporarily the row counter format and providing a correct label for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[top=2.81cm, bottom=2.75cm,right=2cm, left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
   \onehalfspacing
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%% DETTE ER NUMERERING AF RÆKKER I TABELLER
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\newcounter{rowcntr}

\newcounter{interviewee}
\newcounter{subquestion}

\renewcommand{\theinterviewee}{\Alph{interviewee}}

% This is meant for a subquestion
\newcommand{\subquest}{%
  \stepcounter{subquestion}% 
  \addtocounter{rowcntr}{-1}%
  \let\origtherowcntr\therowcntr%
  \renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\origtherowcntr.\alph{subquestion}}%
  \refstepcounter{rowcntr}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\prepareresultsections}{%
  \setcounter{rowcntr}{0}
  \@addtoreset{rowcntr}{table}
  % Change the rowcntr format for the interview results
  \renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\theinterviewee.\arabic{rowcntr}}
}
\makeatother



\newcommand{\resultsection}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{interviewee}%
  \section*{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
% Assuming arabic numbers for the table number -- in case of bottom table caption, we have to increase the table number by one, only for output. 
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\@arabic{\numexpr\c@table+1}.\arabic{rowcntr}}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}c}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rowcntr}{0}\setcounter{subquestion}{0}}
%%% DETTE ER NUMERERING AF RÆKKER I TABELLER
\begin{document}


\section*{Interview questions}
The following table contains my interview questions and explanation

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|N| c | V{7.6cm} | V{7.6cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Question}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Explanation}} \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Interview phase 1}\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|C{17.5cm}|}{\textit{Text This phase focus on ...TextTextTextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText TextText TextTextText TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text }}\\ \hline
   \label{que:1} & A & Do you think ...? & This is a good question.\\
   \label{que:2} & C & Do you feel Text & This is a good question.\\
   \label{que:3} & E & What do you think of your previous boss & Relationship between employee and employer text Text textText text Text text Text text.\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Interview phase 2}\\ \hline
   \multicolumn{4}{|C{17.5cm}|}{\textit{Text This phase focus on ... }}\\ \hline
   \label{que:4} & D & Is this ...? & Good question.\\
   \label{que:5} & I & Do you like Text  & A good question.\\
   \label{que:6} & A & what do you think of your mother & Relationship \\ \hline

   \caption {Questions and explanation} \label{tab:interviewspg}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}


\prepareresultsections
\resultsection{Interview answers person \theinterviewee}
The following section contains the answers from interviewperson \theinterviewee
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|N|  V{8.3cm} | V{8.3cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Question}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Answer}} \\ \hline
   \label{QA:1} &  Do you think ...? & Yes I think.\\
   \label{QA:2} &  Do you feel Text & I feel a lot of text.\\
   \label{QA:3} & What do you think of your previous boss & I hated him.\\
   \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\subquest\therowcntr\label{QA:3a}} & \textbf{This is an unexpected follow up question} \textbf{Why did you hate him?} & \textbf{Because he was evil.}\\
   \label{QA:4} &  Is this ...? & Yes\\
   \label{QA:5} & Do you like Text  & Text is good.\\
   \label{QA6:6} & what do you think of your mother & I really like my mother \\ \hline

   \caption {Questions and answers} \label{tab:interviewspgA}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}





\resultsection{Interview answers person \theinterviewee}
The following section contains the answers from interviewperson \theinterviewee

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|N|  V{8.3cm} | V{8.3cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Question}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Answer}} \\ \hline
   \label{QB:1} &  Do you think ...? & No\\
   \label{QB:2} &  Do you feel Text & No you can't feel text\\
   \label{QB:3} & What do you think of your previous boss & She was okay\\
   \label{QB:4} &  Is this ...? & No\\
   \label{QB:5} & Do you like Text  & Text is bad.\\
   \label{QB:6} & what do you think of your mother & I would like to not answer that \\ \hline

   \caption {Questions and answers} \label{tab:interviewspgB}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Better approaches need more information and more thorough design,as it stands, the desired features are not clearly stated.

[image]

Comment: You are amazing! 
Thank you!
I have 2 questions:
1) Is it possible to have a N command which can label table rows "Table number.rownumber" ex 1.1,1.2,1.3 like this one:
\renewcommand{\therowcntr}{\@arabic{\numexpr\c@table+1}.\arabic{rowcntr}}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr}c}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rowcntr}{0}}

And the new one which can label table rows "rownumber" ex 1,2,3,4 like:

Comment: I will look tomorrow, for now it is too late for me ;-)

Comment: Okay thank you :-)
The second question is:
2) Is it possible to also make a table with 3 columns where the 1. column contains label with "Question 1 Person A "= QA1 in row 1  and "Answer 1 Person A"=AA1 in row 2.
Like this:
QA1 & Question 1 person A\\
AA1 & Answer 1 person A\\
QA2 & Question 2 person A\\
AA2 & Answer 1 person A\\
QA2.a & Unexpected Question person A\\
AA2.a & Unexpected answer person A\\
Same principle with person B and C
Thank you

Comment: @Jonas: Actually, I think you're requesting things which weren't in your question and I don't like changed questions which lead to a state which leaves the current effort useless. The whole tabular approach etc. isn't well designed yet and repairing one thing at one end removes something at the other end.

Comment: @ Christian I'm sorry. I was just looking at different options :-)
Let me try to clarify the intention of this post:
I am conducting a series of interviews with person A,B,C,D ect.
I have prepared an "interview model", with question I'm going to ask (Every question is labeled with 1,2,3,4) (Table questions and explanations)
Lets say I interview person A, every question I ask person A will be labeled A.1,A,2,A3 ect. "A" corresponds to interview person A and "1" corresponds to question 1 in the "interviewmodel".
Lets say I ask a follow up question (which is not in the "Interviewmodel") ...

Comment: ... this question should be labled as a sub question to the previously asked qustion (in this case A1) this sub question should then be labled as A1.a. 
If I asked another sub question it should be labeled A.1.b ect.
In question 10 (A.10) I could ask yet another follow up question which then should be labeled A.10.a.
This is repeated for person B (B.1,B.2,B.3,B.3.a,B.4) and C (C.1,C.2,C.2.a, ect)
Thereby all the "interview model questions" and the result questions/answers are directly linked, and unexpected follow up questions are labeled as sub questions to the previously asked ...

Comment: ... "interview model question"
Does this make sense?
Thank you very much for your time!
I really appreciate your help!